# Nova Tool not updating

Tags: laravel

I'm making a Laravel Nova app. I'm trying to create a Nova Tool to import users.
The tool creates just fine, however when i update the code it does not show.

I've digged a bit into this, and the problem seems to be that the tool in the Vendor folder does not get updated.

When i do npm run dev or npm run prod, the tool files get updated inside the /nova-components/{componentname} folder, and not in the vendor folder, which is getting loaded by Nova.

I'm using Xampp on windows.
Inside my nova service provider:

```
    /**
     * Get the tools that should be listed in the Nova sidebar.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function tools()
    {
        return [
            new UserImport()
        ];
    }
```

My composer file:

```
"require": {
    "Vrumona/UserImport": "*"
},
"repositories": [
      {
          "type": "path",
          "url": "./nova"
      },
      {
          "type": "path",
          "url": "./nova-components/UserImport"
      }
  ],
```

How do make sure the Tool gets updated in the composer vendor folder?

I can delete the vendor folder and run composer install, but this is a bit tedious while developping.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, what you have _should_ be working. It should have created a symbolic link to your `UserImport` package when you run `composer update`. What do you see when you run that command? Do you see something like `Symlinking from ..` or `Mirrored from ..`? The latter would mean symlinks aren't available so the fallback is mirroring which might be causing the issue you're seeing.

Comment: When i run composer update i only see this: Updating dependencies (including require-dev), Nothing to install or update, Generating autoload files

Comment: Ive deleted the folders, run Composer Update again and it said this: Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing vrumona/userimport (dev-master)
    Mirrored from ./nova-components/UserImport\

  - Installing laravel/nova (dev-master)
    Mirrored from ./nova\

Comment: Ah, okay. Since it's being mirrored it's just a copy of the directory as opposed to a symlink which would be picking up the changes. I suspect it's a Windows issue although not certain; I recall having symbolic link issues back when I was on a Windows machine. You might try searching for things like "composer symlink on windows" to see if any solutions exists. Hope this helps.

Comment: I got it fixed by forcing a symlink in the composer file. Thanks for pointing this out!, please make an answer to i can accept.

Comment: Awesome, well done! I've added an answer so future users can benefit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that composer is not symlinking the package but rather mirroring. You can confirm by seeing what the output is when you run `composer update` -- if you see `Mirrored from ...` then symlinks are unavailable which will cause the issue that you're seeing.

As you noticed, you can force symlinks in the composer file using:

```
"options": {
    "symlink": true // Will force symlinks
}
```

And the relevant documentation if needed: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 